# ASP VB.net How to avoid full page refresh on link button click in programmatically created in Grid View

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev0KF.jpg)I have created a Gridview control and programmatically populated it with a link button in each row. Every time I click link button , it refreshes full page.

My html code is

```html
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <updatepanel  id="upGVUpdate" runat="server" >
    <table width ="100%">
        <tr align ="center" >
            <td><asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
      </updatepanel>    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and Code behind is

```
Protected Sub gv_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gv.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim lbUpdate = New LinkButton
        lbUpdate.ID = "Update_" & e.Row.Cells(1).Text
        lbUpdate.Text = "Update"
        AddHandler lbUpdate.Click, AddressOf Update_Clicked
        e.Row.Cells(3).Controls.Add(lbUpdate)
    End If
End Sub
```

and Grid View is

Since actual data rows in Grid view are too much it take lot of time after clicking a link button (update) and unnecessary  refreshing the whole page.

Pl help how to avoid this.

Comment: You need to use an **UpdatePanel** on your aspx page. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bb386454(v=vs.100) for more info

Comment: Use an updatePanel or even raw Ajax

Comment: How can I place only Link button in UpdatePanel? I tried placing table in updatePanel. But it is refreshing the whole page.

Comment: We can't help you easily without seeing your code attempt. Please edit the question.

Comment: question updated